# Mysql query on radio values: Reset all values and change one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 query's in which first one is making all the fields zero and second one updates column but i want these queries into on query change cover_image = 0 first then cover_image = 1

```
Update gallery set cover_image = 0 Where gallery_id = 1;
Update gallery set cover_image = 1 Where ID = 4 AND gallery_id = 1;
```

How can i do this with single query?

Comment: Please change the title to be more explicit if you just want to merge these query's.

Answer (score 2):

I just found answer.

```
UPDATE gallery SET cover_image = IF(id='4', '1','0') WHERE gallery_id = 1
```

It is equal to

```
Update gallery set cover_image = 0 Where gallery_id = 1;
Update gallery set cover_image = 1 Where ID = 4 AND gallery_id = 1;
```